# ASP.NET ListView Unable To Dynamically Fire SelectedIndexChanging

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, listview, listviewitem

```
protected void pnlFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickablePanel pnlFriends = sender as ClickablePanel;
    lvFriends.SelectedIndex = ((ListViewItem)pnlFriends.Parent).DisplayIndex;
}
```

Does not hit the following:

```
protected void lvFriends_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender,  
ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GetConversation(lvFriends.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex][0].ToString());
}
```

How come? I used to get this working with WinForms using .Selected = true; However, it looks like there is absolutely no way to dynamically fire the ListViewSelectedIndexChanging event.

Any ideas how can I get this to work properly? Thank you.

## EDIT

I am trying to select a ListView Item, and when the index changes. I am trying to populate a second ListView on the same page. I need to handle the first event when the index changes.

## UPDATE (RESOLVED)

```
protected void lvFriends_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender,  ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    lvFriends.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    lvFriends.DataSource = Friendship.GetFriends(User.Identity.Name, false);
    lvFriends.DataBind();
    GetConversation(lvFriends.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex][0].ToString());
}

protected void pnlFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickablePanel pnlFriends = sender as ClickablePanel;
    lvFriends.SelectItem(((ListViewItem)pnlFriends.Parent).DisplayIndex);
}
```

^ Works flawlessly.
I guess somehow, .`SelectItem` triggers `ListViewSelectEventArgs` and we would have to handle it by setting `.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;` and then rebinding the data to display the selected item properly.

Now what I can do with the code above is just call this ->                                     `lvFriends.SelectItem(int);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
protected void lvFriends_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender,  ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    lvFriends.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    lvFriends.DataSource = Friendship.GetFriends(User.Identity.Name, false);
    lvFriends.DataBind();
    GetConversation(lvFriends.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex][0].ToString());
}

protected void pnlFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickablePanel pnlFriends = sender as ClickablePanel;
    lvFriends.SelectItem(((ListViewItem)pnlFriends.Parent).DisplayIndex);
}
```

Also, please check the original question! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the ASP.Net page life cycle business. The "lvFriends_SelectedIndexChanging"  event and the "pnlFriends_Click" event happen at the same life cycle. Basically after postback, asp.net checks to see if the lvlFriends index has changed. It hasn't so it continues on with the rest of the events from the postback. Now its in the next part of the lifecycle. It is handling the "pnlFriends_Click" event. It does the processing for it. If it happens to do something that changes the index of the lvlFriends, it doesn't get captured. The ASP.Net page life cycle doesn't go back after processing events from a set of controls to see if that processing has resulted in events on yet other controls.

But to achieve what you want, rather than changing the index or expecting to fire an event. You will have to explicitly  call the method.

```
protected void pnlFriends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickablePanel pnlFriends = sender as ClickablePanel;
    lvFriends.SelectedIndex = ((ListViewItem)pnlFriends.Parent).DisplayIndex;
    lvFriends_SelectedIndexChanging(lvFriends, new ListViewSelectEventArgs() {// TODO: build the event args object properly});
}
```

Comment: Hi, I resolved the issue with the code shown in my updated question. Please check it out if you have time and let me know what you think. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Hard to tell. You seem to be rebinding lvFriends list each time. Not sure if that is a good idea, depending on how expensive the GetFriends operation is. How about in your original code just moving the GetConversations() method line into the  pnlFriends_Click method? Does that not work?